# Remove Backslash and Quotations in R

Tags: r, string, quotes, backslash

How do I remove the quotes from the following string in R?

```
test = "\"LAST4\""
noquote(test)
[1] "LAST4"
```

I'm reading in the data manually and I can't remove the quotations and backslashes.

Comment: What do you mean "I'm reading the data in manually"? It would be better to fix the problem at the time of import rather than later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to escape anything if you don't use a regex:

```
gsub('\"', "", test, fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "LAST4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
gsub("\\\"","",test)
#[1] "LAST4"
```

**AMEND** :

@Roland 's solution improves both readability and performance :

```
require(rbenchmark)
test = "\"LAST4\""

a <- function() gsub("\\\"","",test)
b <- function() gsub('\"', "", test, fixed = TRUE)

benchmark(a(), b(), replications=10^7)
#  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#1  a()     10000000  87.216    1.801    87.914        0          0         0
#2  b()     10000000  48.430    1.000    46.989        0          0         0
```

Comment: Try actually benchmarking the function evaluation: `benchmark(a(), b(), replications=10^5)`

Comment: Oh, indeed, how stupid am I… Thank you @Roland !
I will amend my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in: "R - gsub replacing backslashes" worked for me.

Example:

```
library(stringr)
df$variable <- str_replace(df$variable,"\\\\\\\","")

df$variable before: "xyz\"
df$variable after:"xyz"
```